# tinymce4 blur event acts like focus event

Tags: focus, blur, tinymce-4

I am using `tinyMCE4` in one of my projects and want to add custom methods on different events the editor instance of tinyMCE provides. I am trying to usw the `focus` and `blur` events as follows.

```
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on("focus", function(event) {
            // Do something when editor is focused.
        }); 
        editor.on("blur", function(event) {
            // Do something when editor is blurred.
        });
    }
```

The `focus` event works absolutely fine but the `blur`event is not triggered when tinyMCE loses focus, but is triggered when it gets focused. why is this so ? is this a bug ?

Here is a [**`jsfiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/e99xf/21/) displaying the above issue. Click on the launch button and then click on the textarea. `blur` event is triggered on `focus` and not triggered on `blur`.